# How do I use Gmail's SMTP client to send an email to myself in C# without enabling access for less secure apps in Gmail settings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

I'm working on an ASP.NET Web Forms app and I'm trying to programmatically  send an email to myself. I'm using Gmail's SMTP client, and all is well except that when I send my message, I get this error:

> "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure
> connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
> was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"

If I go into my gmail account settings and enable an option that allows me to allow access for "less secure apps", everything works fine. I'm wondering how I can send my email with having this option enabled.

```cs
protected void sendEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypassword"),
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        EnableSsl = true
    };
    
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress("myusername@gmail.com", "Torchedmuffinz");
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress("myusername@gmail.com", "Torchedmuffinz");
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
    message.Subject = "test";
    message.Body = "test";
    Attachment attachFile = new Attachment(@"pathtofile");
    message.Attachments.Add(attachFile);

    try { client.Send(message); }
    catch (Exception email_exception)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(email_exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unsure what you mean. You are using a system (GMAIL) that has **set requirements** in order for you to use it...

Comment: @EdSf I was unsure of what those requirements were. After digging a bit more, I found an article [link](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/07/21/gmail-starts-block-less-secure-apps-enable-access/) that suggests that they switched to "OAuth 2.0" at some point but only recently started enforcing it. Assuming that my problem comes from that, I am now attempting to learn how to make my app comply to that.

Comment: @Torchedmuffinz - I tried your code and it works for me if I change the port to 25 instead of 587.

Comment: @user1 Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that, but it doesn't work for me. I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried using an email client (like Outlook) and making sure you can successfully send email using it?  I only ask because Gmail does have some funny authentication gotchas.  That would at least verify if there's an issue with your code, or your account.

Comment: @Torchedmuffinz - I poked through my gmail settings and noticed that I have both POP and Imap enabled under the "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" tab. Not sure if this has any effect on allowing my code to send an email. Also try allowing access to applications using this link https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: @Mike Nice suggestion. I tried that and it worked perfectly. So I am fairly confident that my code is okay. I think I can narrow it down being a gmail specific problem.

Comment: @user1 Definitely some good thoughts. Unfortunately, I too have those same options set and the link didn't work.

Comment: @Torchedmuffinz Did you find a solution? Please, post an answer

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko Hmm, I think I ended up finding a solution to this, I'll try to dig around when I'm not at work and post it soon!

Answer (score 0):

Gmail port 587 does not support SSL.

I think the following code should work for you.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From=new MailAddress("yourmail@gmail.com");
msg.To.Add("receiver@receiverdomain.com");
msg.Subject="Your Subject";
msg.Body="Message content is going to be here";
msg.IsBodyHtml=false; //if you are going to send an html content, you have to make this true

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
client.Port=587;

NetworkCredential credential=new NetworkCredential("yourmail@gmail.com","your gmail password");
client.UseDefaultCredentials=false;
client.Credentials=credential;
client.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to use Google SMTP servers without 'Allow less secure apps' option, but you cannot use your standard google username and password. See my instructions on other post:

[Is there a way to use ASP.NET to send email through a Google Apps acccount without selecting the 'Allow less secure apps' option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699405/is-there-a-way-to-use-asp-net-to-send-email-through-a-google-apps-acccount-witho/35706567#35706567)