# SMTP server Error in ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

Im Develop the Asp.net web application.  im Add the Email part,
i had a following error cant sent the email.

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
```

### Im try to fix it more than 5 hours, but i cant fix this, i was refer all of Stack overflow question

**class**

```
 public static void SendEmail(string receientEmail, string subject, string body) {
            //Email
            using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage()) {

                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"]);

                mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                mailMessage.Body = body;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(receientEmail));
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
                smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]);
                System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                NetworkCred.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
                NetworkCred.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
                smtp.Send(mailMessage);
 }
```

---

**WebConfig**

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="AdminLoginID" value="admin"/>
    <add key="AdminPassword" value="123"/>
<!--Email Setting-->
    <add key ="Host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
       <add key ="EnableSsl" value="true"/>
    <add key ="UserName" value="cafe****@gmail.com"/>
      <add key ="Password" value="****"/>
    <add key ="Port" value="587"/>     
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Try following things: 1. Remove the line `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` 2. Confirm that username and password provided are correct.

Comment: Sir, Im Removed, but not work

Comment: Instead of getting values from ConfigurationManager, try hard coding values directly first. See if email is being sent.

Comment: Ooh, I forgot to mention one more thing. For sending mail using gmail server, you have to first set access to less secure apps. You can do that [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) from google's settings. If you don't do that, you get "Authentication required" error.

Comment: sir, in try to sign in the google, what happen this, `This setting is not available for accounts with 2-Step Verification enabled. Such accounts require an application-specific password for less secure apps access`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending mail using gmail smtp server, you have to first **set access to less secure apps**. You can do that [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) from google's settings. If you don't do that, you get "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required." error.

You can not turn on access to less secure apps if google two step verification is enabled. For sake of code simplicity(Prone to risk), I suggest you should turn off two step verification on your google account and then turn on access to less secure apps.

**Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699405/is-there-a-way-to-use-asp-net-to-send-email-through-a-google-apps-acccount-witho) to know more about this.**

The only problem with your code is `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;`.
If you remove that line then, your code should work with other smtp servers which do not have two step verification enabled.

Comment: Thank you very much sir,

Comment: Sir, finally its working, Thanks for  your valuable time

Answer (score 1):

You supply `NetworkCredentials` and then overwrite them with `UseDefaultCredentials` that is set to true.

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

See the [Microsoft Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx) for more detail

Comment: Then take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp).